# Verify Quality of Video and Audio Played using Automation Scripts

Tags: automated-testing

I have few audio and video files which I need to play and verify the files are playing perfect or there is choppy audio or issues with pixel when videos are playing.

We can easily verify this manually, But How can I make my automation script know this. What should be the Pass/Fail criteria for automation script to make a bad file to file and good file to pass.

Thanks,
Sashi

Comment: Do you have a realizable definition of choppy? One possibility is that it takes longer to play back than the nominal runtime. Also, you may have to do some signature analysis of the audio to look for unexpected dropouts. As for video, I know of nothing other than doing a frame by frame capture and comparison to give you what you want.

Comment: What testing framework are you expecting to use for this @Sashi? Selenium, Cypress, ad-hoc?

Answer (score 2):

Check out open source MediaInfo: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo

Download the DLL and incorporate into your automation solution.

You can extrapolate metadata for video (codec, frame rate, bit rate, etc.) and audio (codec, sample rate, etc.) & compare to expected / known values for pass / fail criteria.

Choppy videos in particular may exhibit frame and bit rate values outside of your expected values.

Answer (score 2):

There are professional audio/video quality analyzers from companies like Rohde & Schwartz (https://www.rohde-schwarz.com), which you can plug into a test automation pipeline.

They do cost a lot of $$$ though and require professional knowledge to operate, so in your case that would most probably be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFplay . Its a command line player which can be invoked through a script(I use perl). Then you can monitor its output for any kind of error. Although it will not give pixel level information but it can be used for high level testing and monitoring of a video stream.

Answer (score 1):

For audio quality you can use Matlab PSQM script I used it a long time ago but can't find the reference to it, you can interface Matlab from Perl, Python and probably other languages too. Alternatively you can use the C [PESQ code from ITU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329403/how-to-start-a-voice-quality-pesq-test).

A quick found this Python [Google Video Quality Tool](https://code.google.com/p/video-tester/)